# How to make a discord bot read another bot's embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I am trying to make a companion bot for a bot called "EPIC RPG" it is a game bot and there are some events that I would like my bot to ping a role so people notice there is an event going on but I just can't make my bot read the embed, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the message author is that specific bot using it's ID then you can check the embeds of the message sent by that bot, if any, using [`Message.embeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds)

```js
client.on((message) => {
  if (message.author.id === 'BOT_ID') {
    if (message.embeds) {
      const embed = message.embeds[0]
      if (embed.title === 'EVENT') {
        return message.channel.send('EVENT STARTED')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: ```js
MessageEmbed {
  type: 'rich',
  title: undefined,
  description: undefined,
  url: undefined,
  color: 10181046,
  timestamp: null,
  fields: [
    {
      value: 'Type **CATCH** (once) to collect some coins! The reward depend on how much players join\n' +
        '**Coins per player: 2650 ~ 117600**',
      name: "**IT'S RAINING COINS <:coin:541384484201693185>**",
      inline: false
    }
  ],
  thumbnail: null,
  image: null,
  video: null,
  author: null,
  provider: null,
  footer: null,
  files: []
}
```
 that's the embed any help i still don't understand

Comment: Well, what events would you like to trigger role mentioning?